# Can't close port when using Docker

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, docker, ufw

I have Ubuntu 16.04 server with an app running using Docker:

```
  web: &django
    restart: always
    environment:
      - DJANGO_SECRET_KEY=local
    image: web
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./compose/production/web/Dockerfile
    command: /gunicorn.sh
    volumes:
      - /static:/static
      - /media:/media
    depends_on:
      - postgres
      - redis
    links:
      - redis
    ports:
      - "8083:5000"
    env_file: .env
```

In Ubuntu server nginx config I have:

`proxy_pass http://0.0.0.0:8083;`

but when I scan the server using *nmap* I see that port `8083` is open:

```
PORT STATE SERVICE
80/tcp open http
443/tcp open https
8083/tcp open us-srv
```

Even if I close it:

```
ufw deny 8083
ufw deny 8083/tcp
```

and scan again using nmap it seems to be open. How can I close this port?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want a docker container to open a port, than **don't publish that port** in the first place.
Simply remove the port from you container configuration.

Simply remove that mapping:

```
ports:
  - "8083:5000"
```

(Background: **docker creates firewall rules** that on the host will open up the ports you publish to make the container accessible to the world. Those rules take precedence over that `ufw deny` command. https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/container-networking/)

Comment: ok, but when I will remove this mapping, Nginx installed on my host machine will can not access this container - proxy_pass http://0.0.0.0:8083; - not sure, but maybe this is okay that port 8083 is open?

Comment: port 8083 should be open only for host machine not to the world

Comment: Or you could simply connect to port 5000 on the container withpout publishing a port